# Why can't sp_delete_backuphistory be found?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have some code that executes a very simple executenonquery using the msdb database
and the sp_delete_backuphistory stored proc.

The code has not changed since 2008.
The code runs on a Windows 7 server, using SQL Server 2012.

However, when I run the exe on a Windows 2012 Server, using SQL Server 2012 the call fails with:
an exception "Cannot find sp_delete_backuphistory".

Anybody have ANY clue why it would fail on Windows 2012 server?

Comment: Can you please check your permissions and make sure you have permissions to run the stored procedure?

SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (sp_delete_backuphistory, 'OBJECT')

Comment: I get this:  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'sp_delete_backuphistory'.

Comment: SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions ('sp_delete_backuphistory', 'OBJECT')

Comment: Here are the results:  entity_name subentity_name permission_name
sp_delete_backuphistory  SELECT
sp_delete_backuphistory  UPDATE
sp_delete_backuphistory  REFERENCES
sp_delete_backuphistory  INSERT
sp_delete_backuphistory  DELETE
sp_delete_backuphistory  EXECUTE
sp_delete_backuphistory  RECEIVE
sp_delete_backuphistory  VIEW CHANGE TRACKING
sp_delete_backuphistory  VIEW DEFINITION
sp_delete_backuphistory  ALTER
sp_delete_backuphistory  TAKE OWNERSHIP
sp_delete_backuphistory  CONTROL

Comment: So I have execute rights  ( on both machines )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was we weren't using the SA account.